# How can I map the matrix monotone to completely monotone function?

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis

I currently study matrix monotone. I met some trouble with the proof below.

Prove if $f: \mathbb{R}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a matrix monotone function, then $-f$ is a completely monotone function.

I can give an example for the proof below.
$f(x)=logx$ is matrix monotone, and then it satisfies the condition for the completely monotone function.

And I know the definition completely monotone funciton $a function f:(0,\infty) \rightarrow[0, \infty)$ is said to be completely monotone if $(-1)^{k} f^{(k)} \geq 0$ for $x>0$ and $ k=0, 1, 2, \dots$

I can not understand how to prove it generally.
Can anyone give me some concepts or theorems about the question?

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be some problems here. First, $-\log$ is not positive on $(0,\infty)$, and even if you replace it by something like $-\log(1+\cdot)$, the function and its derivative have the same sign.

What is true is that every matrix monotone function $f\colon (0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ is a *Bernstein function*, namely $(-1)^k f^{(k)}\leq 0$ for $k\geq 1$. In other words, $f'$ is completely monotone. This follows from Löwner's theorem:

The function $f$ has an integral representation of the form
$$
f(x)=\int_0^1\frac{x}{t+(1-t)x}\,d\mu(t)=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{tx^{-1}+(1-t)}\,d\mu(t)
$$
with a positive measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$.

By induction and the dominated convergence theorem one can show,
$$
f^{(k)}(x)=-(-1)^k k!\int_0^1\frac{t(1-t)^{k-1}}{(t+(1-t)x)^{k+1}}\,d\mu(t),
$$
which implies $(-1)^kf^{(k)}\leq 0$, so that $f$ is indeed a Bernstein function.